# how to open popup on page init in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code

On pageinit popup getting opened but it is closing again.

What do I have to do to make it stay?

```
$(document).delegate("#pageone", "pageinit", function () {
   alert("hi");
   $("#popupdiv").trigger("click"); //openvipPopup is the id of the anchor for popup
});
```

using

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
      <h1>Solution Location</h1>
      <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">Cancel</a>
      <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" 
       data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" id="setURL">Done</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
        <label for="name">Set URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="solutionURL" id="solutionURL" 
         value="http://demo.iallways.com/iConfig" style="width:350px;" />
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#popupDialog" data-rel="popup" 
  class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all" data-position-to="window" 
  id="popupdiv"> Solution Location</a>
```

Comment: given $( "#popupDialog" ).popup( "open" ); in document .ready function throwing following error  Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Comment: Try `$(document).delegate("#pageone", "pageshow"...`